# Pass an id from view to js controller and then to CI controller

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am fairly new to angular js and I am stuck on to pass an id from view to js controller and then to CI controller.

In view I am having a `vid`:

```
<td><a href="" class="btn btn-square blue btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o faa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="getID(vehicle.vid)"></i></a></td>
```

In js controller :

```
$scope.getID = function(myID){
    //here i need help
    };
```

Somebody please help.

Comment: add  ng-click="getID(vehicle.vid)" in anchor tag element  and console id    $scope.getID = function(myID){
   console.log(myID);
    };

Comment: it returns the coresponding id.how could I pass this id to my ci controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http method to pass id to CI controller

```
  $http({headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        url: path_to_CI_routes + "/contoller_name/function",
                        method: "POST",
  data:
                            $.param
                            ({
                                'id': myID
                            }), })
                        .then(function mySucces(response) {
 });
```

Comment: Thank you.I have another doubt.Here on the success reponse im getting an array.How can i pass the result to another contoller?

Comment: are you talking about CI controller ? or angular controller ?

Comment: again  You can use  http method to pass response to CI controller     .then(function mySucces(response) { $http({headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        url: path_to_CI_routes + "/contoller_name/function",
                        method: "POST",
  data:
                            $.param
                            ({
                                'array': response.data
                            }), })
                        .then(function mySucces(response) {
 });   });

Comment: i dont know whether my requirement  way  is right on not.i have to pass that array result to a view page.This is my actual requirement.So i load that view page on my ci controller.On this ci controller i want to get this array result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118605/discussion-between-jatinder-kaur-and-anju).